# Access GPIO Pins in OpenELEC

Tags: gpio, openelec

I want to use the GPIO Pins to controll a 433Hz transmitter on a pi 2 with openelec. It is possible to use ssh, but I am not able to install the software (Commands are in description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOgJtNaJZ_4). The software is running perfectly on raspbian and maybe i can built it there and copy to openelec.

Because of lags in the commands of openelec, i cannot run the software, e.g. missing `sudo`. Any advice, how i can do this?

Edit: I cannot access the console on the pi, but ssh is possible.

Comment: It's massively more straightforward to do this running Kodi on Raspbian, rather than OpenELEC. There isn't *that* much performance difference between the two. If you don't absolutely, positively *need* it to boot that few seconds faster I would just re-image your Pi with Raspbian and start from there.

Comment: Did you test Kodi on Raspbian? I had terrible performance, but maybe it was caused by other programms running

Comment: I've yet to have any serious issues with it on a pi 2.

Comment: I think goobering's probably right, but I've used neither Kodi nor OpenELEC.   Anyway, there must be a root user, the issue is accessing the account.   Can you get a console?  Preferably not inside the GUI, but by checking Ctrl-Alt-F1 through F6.   They probably aren't there though, and if there's then no terminal app in the interface, the system really is black boxed and would require a lot of hacking to do this kind of thing with.

Comment: OpenELEC is just another GNU/Linux distribution centred around Kodi. I wouldn't bet OpenELEC maintainers have disabled GPIO access from their Pi-dedicated release so GPIOs must probably be accessible. If your software can be converted into Python, that'd be your best option as Kodi extensions mostly use Python. Ultimately you can also run native executables from Python, too. And if my memory serves me well, Kodi runs as `root` on OpenELEC — allright, not the best but no need for `sudo`. Otherwise you still have the option to compile your custom flavour using their development environment.

Comment: please do not post (or consult) youtube videos. If anyone has any important information to share, they'll share it was plain text.

Comment: @goobering how did you manage kodi running? It's even lagging in 720p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Solution: OSMC. It's nearly the same like OpenELEC, but it has more console programms

Solution: installing kodi on Raspbian. Don't forget to split memory between CPU and GPU